# How do you switch cameras?

Tags: javascript, html5-video, opentok

I have a simple OpenTOK web conferencing application that works well. But my users may have multiple USB cameras and I need to be able to allow them to select a different camera under program control. I know they can go to the top of Chrome and click on the camera Icon, but it would be preferable to have a popup in my web application. I have seen this done but have no clue how to do it. Google has not as of yet yielded any search results either. Does anyone know? I need to switch audio sources as well if that is similar. I only care about Chrome for now.

Thanks!

Comment: This is NOT a duplicate. I do not want to switch to a rear camera on a mobile device. I want to change to a different USB camera on a MAC or PC.

Comment: I agree, not a duplicate. You cannot pick webcam device with OpenTok API currently, but it is a feature OpenTok is working on. Check for updates in the coming weeks.